# unable to execute onload() of child html called inside parent jsp div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

below is the code of the parent jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.ForEach"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="com.sal.bean.CompanyBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script>
 /* function loadHTML(pageName) {
  //alert(pageName);
  var name = pageName + ".html";
  //alert(name);
  $('#my_div').load(name + ' #' + pageName);
  //alert("2"); */
  
  
  function loadHTML(pageName) {
   var name = pageName + ".html";
  
    $('#my_div').load(name);
}
 
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <%
  List<CompanyBean> cmpList = (List<CompanyBean>) request
    .getAttribute("CompDtl");
  Iterator itr = cmpList.iterator();
  CompanyBean cmp = (CompanyBean) itr.next();
 %>
 <div
  style="height: 100px; width: 101%; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80817D; margin: -15px 0px 0px -7px; border-radius: 10px;">

  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
   <li
    style="font-size: 72px; font-family: Verdana; margin-right: 30px; float: right;"><%=cmp.getComp_nm()%></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -7px; border-radius: 10px">
  <div id='cssmenu'
   style="height: 100vh; width: 15%; float: left; background-color: gray;">
   <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
     <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>SETUP</span></a>
      <ul>
       <li onclick="loadHTML('Department')" id="dept"><a href='#'><span
         id="dept">DEPARTMENT</span></a></li>
       <li onclick="loadHTML('Contractor')"><a href='#'><span>CONTRACTOR</span></a></li>
       <li onclick="loadHTML('Salary_mode')" class='last'><a
        href='#'><span>SALARY MODE</span></a></li>
      </ul></li>
     
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul></li>

    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="my_div" style="height:100vh; width:85%; float: left"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the code of child html that is loaded into parent div tag with id = mydiv

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="getDeptID()">
 <div id=Department>
  <script>
   function getDeptID(){
    alert("hello");
   }
  </script>
  <form action="SalaryControl" method="post">
   <div>
    <div style="float: left;">
     <span>Department Code</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="dept_id" tabindex="-1" onFocus="this.blur()"
      value="" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The child gets loaded when i click the respective button in the navigation bar from the main jsp(parent jsp page) successfully but the onload() function in the child html is not getting executed. please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really specifying what you need here but I think that you can accomplish this without running the function located in the child page but instead calling a function in a callback function.

For example:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script>
        function loadHTML(pageName) {
            var name = pageName + ".html";

    $('#my_div').load(name, function() {
        //code that was in getDeptID()
        alert("hello");
     });
}
...
```

There are a lot of different things that you can do in the callback and I'm sure that it can do what you really need it to do.

See the [JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/load/) load function for more info.

Comment: thanks for your responce but it does not resolve my issue. actually i want to get IDs from database and increment then before showing in the UI to store next department. This case happens with contractor and salary mode too. So I cannot write if else on name and ajax for each html load.

Comment: the above solution is good if i need to load only one jsp/html